# Where can I find out what the mime types are for these extensions?

Tags: mime-types

I'm trying to set dynamic compression in IIS 7 and I know I want to enable compression for these file types (along with others): asmx and asjx. However IIS 7 wants their mime type not the extension. Does anyone know where I can find out what the mime-type is? The best I found is text/plain but I highly doubt that's correct.

Comment: ASMX is the extension for the legacy ASP.NET Web Services technology. An ASMX file is never transferred, so mime type is not relevant. I have no idea what asjx is.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Can you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634678/where-to-find-the-response-video-data    Has to do with MIME types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to find this out is to view the pages in a browser, and see what it reports the MIME type as.  For example, in Firefox you could use the [Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) extension, and look for the "Content-Type" header.

Note that if the MIME type does turn out to be something generic like "text/plain", you could end up enabling compression for more than just your *.asmx and *.asjx pages.

**EDIT:** if you are talking about the result of a SOAP call, and not the "friendly" ASMX page that ASP.NET returns to the browser, then the MIME type will probably be "application/soap+xml".

Answer (score 0):

You can look [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/) for a list of all available MIME Types.  Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but I hope it helps.