# Where to find the response video data?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, get, mime-types, inspect-element

This is regarding retrieving data from [Mr.Robot](http://www.usanetwork.com/mrrobot/videos/eps11ones-and-zer0esmpeg)

When I used the [inspect](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) element tool to investigate the traffic I was getting from the site via the network panel, here's  a sample of the data I got [image]

Does anyone know where I can find the data that corresponds to the video(tv episode)?

I saw that the file format of [xhr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) represents the XMLHttpRequest so that is a combination of my browser requesting JSON, HTML, and XML from the web server? (Can someone confirm this as well)

I am trying to find a type that corresponds to one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_file_format) but having no luck.

I am doing this to enhance my knowledge of web and network engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the network tab, if you select to see the headers tab, you can see this information:

```
Request URL:http://api.massrelevance.com/usadigitalapps/mr-robot-tag-mrrobot.json?limit=5&since_id=1039088770827352555_891624285
```

Here, you can see it's a request to a JSON file. :D

[image]

**EDIT**: Try going to this URL when the video is not playing in the browser (for some reason, when I had the page loaded this was returning as blank):

```
http://api.massrelevance.com/usadigitalapps/mr-robot-tag-mrrobot.json?limit=5&since_id=1039263408306586885_20082880
```

That was the request mine was making. In there, you can find a video URL:

```
https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xaf1\/t50.2886-16\/11765169_875397039210031_1586195986_n.mp4
```

Remove the `\` and you'll see the video :D

Comment: How do you know the file contains the actual video data and not metadata or something else?

Comment: I updated my answer with some more information.

You can also look at the console, you can see that there is a WARN output on each of these request. Here you can see it sets the bitrate. Depending on the bitrate, you can see it switched feeds.

Comment: Thanks! I went to that URL. It was a short clip of 15 seconds. Wouldn't this be a clip that someone shared on the site, not the video itself? The video itself is 45 minutes long.

Comment: The request is being made to the server every 2-3 seconds. I'm guessing that it updates the feed based on your bitrate and downloads a 15 second clip based on that. If you get the URLs from each of those request, I bet they'll total the full episode.

Comment: Yeah made sense. Thanks! I let you know if i have any other questions

Comment: @committedandroider No problem. Glad to help. Best way of saying thank you is marking the answer as correct :) hahah.